# How to put row values into columns of one row

Tags: list, workflow

I have a list that is a schedule for employees. Each shift is an item on that list, with name, start time (type Date and Time), end time (type Date and Time) and day of the week (type Date, Calculated column for formatting to display friendly day name, formatted as string). So an employee would have multiple rows/items if they have multiple shifts.

I am creating a workflow to set the values on another list using start time, end time values of items on the schedule list. The second list has only one item per employee, with start time and end time columns(type Date and Time) for each day of the week.

So I am trying to figure out how to get the start end times from each item for each employee on the schedule list, and add/edit them into the appropriate day of the week column on the second list for the employees only row, based on the value of of the day of the week column of the schedule list item that was added or edited.

Currently, workflow runs on create and update. **I'm not really looking for code, i'm hoping someone has had to accomplish something similar, and I'm looking for the logic or method they used to accomplish it so that I can get a clue as to how to approach this.** It has turned out to be a much harder problem than I thought and seems to be a little above me.

And it's even harder than described, but for simplicity, assume there will only be one week where there will be multiple shift items on the employee schedule for each employee for that week, and one entry for each employee with multiple day columns on the other list. If I can solve that, then I'll tackle the problem of differentiating between weeks after that because there will in reality be multiple weeks represented on each list for each employee.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a site workflow for a scheduler workflow, the key actions are Pause and Transition to stage.

You could check below thread for sample.

http://www.fabiangwilliams.com/2013/09/04/creating-a-sharepoint-timer-job-using-sharepoint-designer-2013/